# MultiCore JIT Startup.Profile is not beeing generated

Tags: .net, performance, assembly, .net-4.5, jit

I have tried to experiment with MultiCore JIT on a wpf-application using:

```
App() {

   ProfileOptimization.SetProfileRoot(@"C:\temp\test"); // (a writable directory)
   ProfileOptimization.StartProfile("Startup.Profile");
}
```

This works great on a new wpf-application and *"Startup.Profile"* is generated upon close of the application.

However when using this on the application we produce at work, no *"Startup.Profile"* is generated.

Is there anything that could block the creation of Startup.Profile.

Comment: Not having write access to the c:\temp directory is an obvious explanation.  UAC tends to put a stop to that.  Always favor your own AppData directory.

Comment: Yes I agree, but that is not the focus of the question. Please focus on my question.

Comment: Did you find out what was causing the issue? I also have tried this and found so far that it looks like the application needs to terminate normally by leaving the main method to generate the file. I thought it would stop profiling and write out a file after some time but this seems not to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Please note: the path for `SetProfileRoot()` must exist  (if not create it)